# Why is static function accessible from an extern file?

Tags: c++

Static function is available from outside the file it was declared in.

```cpp
// a.cpp
#include <iostream>

static void helloWorld() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

```cpp
// b.cpp
#include "a.cpp"

int main() {
  helloWorld();
}
```

Am I missing something in my code, which makes the function helloWorld be available from outside its origin file? How can I make it work as intended, without using unnamed namespaces?

Comment: `#include "a.cpp"` you included the file. It's as-if you would have included the whole file as-is  literally in `b.cpp`.

Comment: `#include` means "copy and paste content of this file in place of this directive". It is `static`, but `static` to the `b.cpp` as well, because it was copied and pasted there.

Comment: It's not external. You literally included it in your file.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to use `#include` on source (`.c`, `.cc`, `.cpp`) files.  It should generally only be used on header (`.h`, `.hpp`) files.

Comment: @ssd And how can I link 2 files which were compiled individually? I don't get this.

Comment: Please show how you are compiling individually. Generally speaking you can just compile and link in one go: `g++ a.cpp b.cpp` or compile then link: `g++ -c a.cpp; g++ -c b.cpp; g++ a.o b.o`

Answer (score 3):

`static` doesn't mean that the function is local to the source *file*. There is no concept of different source files in C++ aside from how the preprocessor resolves `#include` directives.

`static` here means that the function should be local to the *translation unit*. The translation unit is what you get after preprocessing the original `.cpp` file, which includes resolving all `#include` directives.

A `#include` directive literally just instructs the preprocessor to take the exact contents of the referenced file and put them at the point of the directive in the translation unit. At the end there is only one long listing of source code making up the unit.

You usually specify which `.cpp` files should form a translation unit by passing the names of these files explicitly to the compiler. It will then make one translation unit out of each given file by applying the preprocessor as discussed above. Afterwards the object files generated from each translation unit are linked together, either implicitly in one invocation of the compiler, or explicitly with another invocation.

So here, depending on how you compile the code, you are either compiling and linking only one translation unit, probably generated from `b.cpp`. This one will look after preprocessing like this:

```
// contents from <iostream> here

static void helloWorld() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  helloWorld();
}
```

It has a `helloWorld` function local to this unit.

Or you are compiling and linking two translation units with the second one being build from `a.cpp` which would look like this after preprocessing:

```
// contents from <iostream> here

static void helloWorld() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

This one also has a `helloWorld` function. But because the function is in both translation units marked as `static` it has internal linkage and the two functions in the two units are not the same function, but share just a name.

Each `.cpp` file is usually meant to be its own translation unit and only header files are meant to appear in multiple translation units. That's why you generally shouldn't include `.cpp` files in other files.

Nothing would change if you used unnamed namespaces instead of the `static` keyword. You can't have an entity local to a specific file in C++, although because `.cpp` files usually should only appear in the single translation unit compiled from them, having a function declared with `static` in a `.cpp` file typically has basically that effect. You are just breaking the convention here by including a `.cpp` file in another.